# Can I use GitHub's Issue Form for PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE?

Tags: github

I really like to use GitHub's [issue form](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#creating-issue-forms). Can I use the same methodology/forms for [Pull Request Template](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository)?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, 29 November 2021. You cannot use GitHub's issue forms to create a `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE`. I've arrived to this conclusion after digging into the GitHub's docs, googling and experimenting with substitution of **.md** for **.yaml**. It simply isn't supported yet -but it would be cool to have this possibility.